# Simple web page to enhance browsing of IMSLP music collections

Tags: php, security

I'm building a simple webpage that allow users to find the intersection of different category lists on a wiki ([imslp.org](https://imslp.org/wiki/Main_Page)) since the site itself does not offer this functionality. I have a simple HTML form that asks users to paste in two URLs and a PHP script that retrieves information from the two wiki pages and produces a set of results that match both categories.

The code works, but I want to make sure I'm not opening myself or users up to any security vulnerabilities before sharing. Does the following seem secure?

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form method="GET" id="webform" name="webform" action="search.php">
    <label for="people_url">Other people URL:</label>
    <input type="text" id="people_url" name="people_url" size="100">
    <label for="pieces_url">Pieces URL:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pieces_url" name="pieces_url" size="100">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

function validate_URL($url)
{
    $url_converted = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    if (!filter_var($url_converted, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        echo 'This is not a valid URL: ' . $url_converted;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function get_IMSLP_category_list($url)
{
    $results_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $start = strpos($results_string, ':{"') + 1;
    $results_string = substr($results_string, $start);
    $end = strpos($results_string, '}') + 1;
    $results_string = substr($results_string, 0, $end);

    $results_dict = json_decode($results_string);

    $results_list = [];
    foreach ($results_dict as $letter => $letter_list) {
        foreach ($letter_list as $result) {
            array_push($results_list, explode('|', $result)[0]);
        }
    }

    return $results_list;
}

function parse_IMSLP_url($url)
{
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parsed_query);

    if (empty($parsed_query)) {
        $main_category = substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 15);
    } else {
        $main_category = substr($parsed_query['title'], 9);
    }

    $query_display_string = $main_category;

    $restrictions = [];
    $exclusions = [];

    if (array_key_exists('intersect', $parsed_query)) {

        $intersection_categories = explode('**', $parsed_query['intersect']);

        foreach ($intersection_categories as $category) {
            if ($category != '') {
                if (substr($category, 0, 1) != '-') {
                    array_push($restrictions, $category);
                } else {
                    array_push($exclusions, $category);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return [$main_category, $restrictions, $exclusions, $query_display_string];
}

function find_intersection($input)
{
    $main_category = $input[0];
    $restrictions = $input[1];
    $exclusions = $input[2];

    $built_url = 'https://imslp.org/index.php?title=Category:' . $main_category;

    if ((!empty($restrictions)) or (!empty($exclusions))) {
        $combined_intersections = array_merge($restrictions, $exclusions);
        $built_url = $built_url . '&intersect=' . implode('**', $combined_intersections);
    }

    $list = get_IMSLP_category_list($built_url);
    return $list;
}

$process_cross_referencing = True;

$people_url = $_GET["people_url"];
if (!validate_url($people_url)) {
    $process_cross_referencing = False;
}

$pieces_url = $_GET["pieces_url"];
if (!validate_url($pieces_url)) {
    $process_cross_referencing = False;
}

if ($process_cross_referencing) {

    $parsed_people = parse_IMSLP_url($people_url);
    $people_list = find_intersection($parsed_people);

    $parsed_pieces = parse_IMSLP_url($pieces_url);
    $pieces_list = find_intersection($parsed_pieces);

    $results_links = [];

    foreach ($pieces_list as $piece) {
        $composer_start = strrpos($piece, '(') + 1;
        $composer_length = strrpos($piece, ')') - $composer_start;

        $composer = substr($piece, $composer_start, $composer_length);

        if (in_array($composer, $people_list)) {
            array_push($results_links, $piece);
        }
    }
    var_dump($results_links);
}
```

User submits URLs with form. A typical URL would look something like this:

`https://imslp.org/index.php?title=Category:Female_people&intersect=Composers**-German_people`

The PHP script retrieves URL strings using `$_GET` and validates them with `validate_URL()`. If the URL comes back valid, the script parses the URLs using `parse_IMSLP_url`. It then rebuilds the URLs to match a template and retrieves the results from the wiki using `find_intersection()` and `get_IMSLP_category_list()`. Finally, the results from both searches are cross-referenced.

Does it look like I might be opening myself up to any security loopholes here? (I'm pretty new to PHP, so any other suggestions would be equally welcome.)

Answer (score 2):

- In `validate_URL()` I recommend that you only call `htmlspecialchars()` when echoing. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4882307/2943403 That said, I don't recommend that you echo anything from inside your function -- use the boolean return values to dictate *if* a validation error should be displayed.

  ```
  function validate_URL(string $url): bool
  {
    return (bool) filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  }
  ```

  The function becomes so small, that it you are effectively replacing a native function so I would recommend not declaring the function at all.
- In `get_IMSLP_category_list()`, I am seeing some classic misuse of `strpos()`.  If you do not explicitly check for a boolean `false` return value, then you risk getting incorrect results where `0` and `false` will collide.  More importantly, why are you conducting string surgery like this at all?  I don't know what your input data looks like, but if it is some sort of formatted string, there is a fair chances that regex will make your code far more readable/comprehensible.  If the incoming data is a json string, then you should decode it straight away and access what you need, directly, without regex.  I can only advise on improvements to this function after knowing exactly what the data looks like and how it might vary.
- In `parse_IMSLP_url()`, `empty()` is an inappropriate call when you are guaranteed that the variable is going to be declared.  You probably only need to make a functionless falsey check `if (!$variable) {`. Don't declare single-use variables.  Don't declare redundant or unnecessary variables. Don't repeat yourself. Only use `array_push()` when you want to add multiple elements to an array at one time. Don't return redundant data from your function.  (sorry so negative)

  ```
  function parse_IMSLP_url(string $url): array
  {
      parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parsed_query);

      $main_category = $parsed_query
          ? substr($parsed_query['title'], 9)
          : substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 15);

      $restrictions = [];
      $exclusions = [];

      if (array_key_exists('intersect', $parsed_query)) {
          foreach (explode('**', $parsed_query['intersect']) as $category) {
              if ($category != '') {
                  if ($category[0] !== '-') {
                      $restrictions[] = $category;
                  } else {
                      $exclusions[] = $category;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return [$main_category, $restrictions, $exclusions];
  }
  ```
- In `find_intersection()`, you know that there will be 3 incoming elements, so instead, just pass the three elements as arguments and spare yourself the declarations in the function body.  `$restrictions` and `$exclusions` are guaranteed so empty is inappropriate.

  ```
  function find_intersection(string $main_category, array $restrictions, array $exclusions): array
  {
      return get_IMSLP_category_list(
          sprintf(
              'https://imslp.org/index.php?title=Category:%s%s',
              $main_category,
              $restrictions || $exclusions
                  ? '&intersect=' . implode('**', array_merge($restrictions, $exclusions))
                  : ''
          )
      );
  }
  ```
- As for the rest of the code...  Use fewer variables as mentioned previously.  Avoid string surgery via multiple cuts.  I'm showing a regex pattern to extract the composer string, but if I knew the format of these strings, I might be able to provide a better pattern.

  ```
  foreach (['people_url', 'pieces_url'] as $url) {
      if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
          exit('Invalid URL: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET[$url], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
      }
  }

  $people_list = find_intersection(...parse_IMSLP_url($_GET['people_url']));
  $pieces_list = find_intersection(...parse_IMSLP_url($_GET['pieces_url']));

  $links = [];
  foreach ($pieces_list as $piece) {
      if (preg_match('~.*\(\K[^()]+(?=\))~', $piece, $composer) && in_array($composer[0], $people_list)) {
          $links[] = $piece;
      }
  }
  var_export($links);
  ```